# Why are some DLL not present in KnownDLLs not loaded from current application directory

Tags: windows, operating-systems, libraries

From what I know, DLL are loaded in this order (simplified) :

1. Is present in memory ?
2. KnownDLLs
3. Curent Application Dir
4. `System32` directory
5. Etc (not in the question scope)

Step to reproduce the behavior :

- Download Process Explorer (Sysinternals)
- Copy `rsaenh.dll` and `bcrypt.dll` (from `C:\Windows\System32`) to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`
- Launch process explorer, Ctrl+D on procexp64 and look for the DLLs

-> See that `rsaenh.dll` is loaded from `System32`, whereas `bcrypt.dll` is loaded from `Temp` folder.

So, why is there a different behavior since both dll are not prevent in KnowDLLs ?

Comment: In which folder is Process Explorer?

Comment: procexp.exe is in my Desktop folder, but its launching a child process procexp64.exe located in <username>\Appdata\Local\Temp folder
Only this one is loading both DLL, but I guess that the test could be made with some others DLLs.

Comment: There is an order of operations where an application will look for a DLL. if `%LocalAppData%/Temp` is being used that is due to the fact the application was designed to use that location. By your own admission, the application's working exectuable directory, is `%LocalAppData%/Temp` due to the fact procexp64.exe is in that directory.

Comment: What do you get from `dumpbin procexp64.exe /imports`?

Comment: What about PATH? E.G., https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/405690-how-to-add-location-of-dll-files-to-the-system-path

Comment: Using `dumpbin procexp34.exe`, there are only a few DLL. **bcrypt** and **rsaenh** are not present.
For @Ramhound, that's exactly my question : why some DLL (not present in KnownDLLs) are loaded on the current directory, and some not.
@DrMoishePippik Path is the last step in search order, so it does not apply in this case.

Comment: Ok, you found they aren't listed in the imports table.  Since they are loaded by application code, not by the OS loader resolving the import table, the rules can be *anything* and can be different for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

The OS provides the application a choice of several different search strategies, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

And of course the application can also implement its own search and pass an absolute path to `LoadLibrary`, bypassing any OS search.

In addition to that, some DLLs are loaded as in-process COM servers, in which case the path information is loaded from the registry (beneath `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, which is a view merging HKLM and HKCU) when the application asks to create an object.